# How to get a list of admins of a given FB page with php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I need to list all admins for a given FB page having the manage_page rules and all tokens: User, Page and Apps.
Would be great if I could get the specifics rules too (editor, publisher etc.)
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/{page_id}/admins` to query for the Page admins, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/admins

Comment: I used: 
$extend_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$pageid."/admins'";
 $resp = file_get_contents($extend_url);
 parse_str($resp,$output);
print_r($output);
but the result is: 
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/106103686088991/admins') [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in ....
Any tips'

Comment: You have a surplus `'` after `/admins` in your URL. Furthermore, you'll need to add a Page Access Token as described in the docs I linked